# Is this forum going to be officialy supported?

Tags: discussion

Do you think the eventually sites like [farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/bespoke/bespoke7.jsp?ICID=I-RASP-HPBLOF-MRO-0055&bespokepage=farnell/en_UK/promotions/rasp-pi-accessories.jsp) , [RS](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/generalDisplay.html?id=raspberrypi) and other big distributors who actively contributed to the initial distribution and testing of the devices, include raspberrypi.se in their links.

Also - are we allowed to add a link to to Wikipedia next to the official pages forum?

In the end.. Do we/you/us intend to approach the official site to ask for linking to rpi.se for users or do is it likely (form experienced moderators) that official sites would not be bothered as it could de centralise their help section?

I know rpi.se will become very popular very quickly and earn its own little corner- but being officially recognised will make this forum boom out of proportion!

Comment: Related Question: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/257/86

Answer (score 2):

> Do you think the eventually sites like farnell and other big distributors who actively contributed to the initial distribution and testing of the devices, include raspberrypi.se in their links.

Possibly. It would take an enterprising user to communicate with the distributors to arrange something. However, since we are not in the habit of answering distribution questions, it's possible we could not offer them much in return.

> Also - are we allowed to add a link to to Wikipedia next to the official pages forum?

Where?

> In the end.. Do we/you/us intend to approach the official site to ask for linking to rpi.se for users or do is it likely (form experienced moderators) that official sites would not be bothered as it could de centralise their help section?

This is in progress. Currently the organisation has not had much to do with us, nor we them. We would like this to change eventually. At first we wished for them to see that we could stand alone as a valuable contribution to the organisation. Hopefully when we graduate from beta we will have proved this.

I know that with AskUbuntu actually became the official help for the Ubuntu organisation, on the grounds that Ubuntu wouldn't have to waste time and money providing their own support. We are not currently expecting anything like this, but at least there you can see precedent.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi  - for example there is a community section- but maybe we can make a new one with support forums, list the official Raspberry Forum.. and this one? I do not just want to do it as it could violate some rules somewhere.. I am not sure.

Comment: aslo http://uk.rs-online.com/web/generalDisplay.html?id=raspberrypi  I forgot about RS - These big companies actually made their own little getting started section but link heavily back to the official forums and Wikipedia.

Comment: @ppumkin Well we are in the links at the bottom.

Comment: oh yea.. I did notice it even I scanned over it several times. hmm

Comment: @ppumkin Please feel free to do some networking on our behalf :)

Comment: Talking with those "big cheeses" is a nightmare :( and I have no entry point to either of them.

Comment: In that case we will get around to it. Bring it up in [chat].