# How would you describe the Raspberry Pi.SE community?

Tags: discussion, promotion

@ppumpkin asked a very interesting [question about whether the Foundation would ever support Raspberry Pi.SE](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/252/86) and mentioned [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi). Specifically, there is a section entitled *Community*, which I think we should add a section to.

How would you describe Raspberry Pi.SE for this purpose?

Comment: Yea, now that seems like something worth working on. I will think about myself and post something later... Hopefully some other people too.  Nice one Alex.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it would strengthen our relationship with the foundation (which is already tenuous) if we are promoting ourselves too much on Wikipedia at their expense.

Nevertheless, I cannot stop you or anyone else from doing it so here is my suggestion. Currently that Wikipedia article doesn't mention anything of the raspberrypi.org forum or any other communities. So if anyone is going to edit it then in order to remain unbiased they will need to research and discuss multiple Raspberry Pi communities, not just ours.

For ourselves to be mentioned in it, that section of the Article needs a lot of work.

Comment: I agree - it makes more sense to mention everyone!

Comment: Do you have access to the Key Dates? When was it proposed, committed, private/public beta?

Comment: I do. Let's take this discussion to [chat].

Comment: It seems like this is all in a very grey area. If things are going to stay cool between SE and the Raspberry Pi founders.. I think somebody has to represent this forum or atleast tell them directly(maybe not even the users of this forum- but the owners of the entire site- I love SE and i dont want to loose this amazing forum!) U knoiw  instead of finding out from bob who told steve whos 10 year old son stumbled upon?

Comment: @ppumkin It is in the works. If you show up in [chat] then you can help.

Comment: I have been popping in there but which room bro? I cannot see any activity

Answer (score 3):

## Stack Exchange

Stack Exchange has a dedicated question and answer site for the Raspberry Pi. It was proposed on Area 51 by *iandotkelly* on 4th December 2011, and quickly went through commitment (2012-04-19) and private beta (2012-06-12). It has been in public beta since 19th June 2012.

At the time of writing, the site was receiving 5.1 questions a day, contributed by 929 users with 95% of questions answered.